# bijection from $(a,b)$ to $\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology, functions, elementary-functions

I need to construct a bijection from an arbitrary interval $(a,b) \to\Bbb R$. I was thinking of somehow using the tangent function because it's asymptotic, but i'm not sure how to get started.

Comment: Map $(a, b)$ to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ using a linear function. Then use $\tan x$.

Answer (score 7):

Even easier: assuming $a<b$, consider $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}. $$
$f(x)$ is monotonic over the interval $(a,b)$ since $f'(x)<0$ and 
$$ \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=+\infty,\qquad \lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=-\infty. $$

Comment: Jack, I'm looking for a function that does what yours does, but has an easy inverse to compute. Yours doesn't seem to have one easy to compute... Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: if $\phi$ is an affine map bringing $(a,b)$ into $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, then $x\in(a,b)\mapsto f(x)=\tan\phi(x)$ has range $\mathbb{R}$ and inverse $\phi^{-1}(\arctan x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a<b$, you can take:
$$f(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{b-a}x+\frac{\pi}{a-b}\cdot\frac{b+a}2\right)$$
the period $P=d(a,b)$ and the function is shifted so that the center is at $x=\frac{a+b}2$. The vertical asymptotes are $x=a$ and $x=b$.